# What software is a software for RNA tertiary structure prediction?

Tags: software, one-topic-per-answer, software-recommendations, structural-biology

[It seems](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/3849/deepmind-just-announced-a-breakthrough-in-protein-folding-what-are-the-conseque) that the prediction of protein folding is a pretty advanced area. Are there options based on some [GDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_distance_test)-like measure? For me, it has relevance in connection with the origin of life (cf. [RNA world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_world)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Rosetta

The protein modeling program **Rosetta** includes RNA structure prediction functionality. I think the most up-to-date tool is the [FARFAR2 protocol](https://new.rosettacommons.org/docs/latest/FARFAR2). You can try it out through the [Rosie FARFAR2 server](https://rosie.rosettacommons.org/farfar2/submit).

Comment: Excellent! And there exists a CASP-like assessment called RNA-Puzzles wow! (I found it through your link. You could incorporate it in your answer.)

Comment: I've posted a [follow-up question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4665/what-software-is-the-best-choice-for-rna-secondary-structure-prediction).

Comment: @WaterMolecule in case you didn't see the comment by OP pointing you to their follow-up question, that question has a $50 bounty which you might be able to answer since the question is so similar: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4665/5.

Comment: @NikeDattani Thanks for the heads up! Unfortunately, I'm not that familiar with the tool. I mostly use Rosetta for proteins.